# How to call an API url from php?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to call an API (mapquest) url from a shared host.

The url works fine, as it shows the expected JSON response when pasted in a browser.

However, I can't make it work from a php page.
I tried both `curl` and `file_get_contents` with no success.

I keep on getting `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` error...

Here is the code I use, which is quite basic...

```
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    if(!$result){
        exit ('cURL ERROR: '.curl_error($ch));
    }
    return var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Opps you didn't set header..

Comment: Are you sending all necessary headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello try some thing like this

```
$query = urlencode('where={"steps":9243}');
$ch = curl_init('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Steps?'.$query);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-Parse-Application-Id: myApplicationID',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: myRestAPIKey',
    'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

refer this link

[Querying API through Curl/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026258/querying-api-through-curl-php)

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

The url was composed of JSON data with spaces.

This part of the URL must be encoded with `urlencode()`, but not the full url.

It works both with `curl` and `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $curlConfig = array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => "http://www.bing.com/",
        CURLOPT_POST           => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
            'field1' => 'some date',
            'field2' => 'some other data',
        )
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
    echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```